GPU passthrough (single GPU machine)
I am interested in a use case where I have a PC running KVM, and I want to map the host's VGA/DVI output to a guest machine. The host machine will not have 2x video cards. The net effect is that, after the host boots, I want it to start the VM guest and for the VGA/DVI output to map to the VM guest virtual machine.
Does anyone have any experience doing something like this? I want to know if it is even possible. Or if there is some technical reason why this cannot be done.
I realise this means I will lose GUI access to the host. That is intentional. The goal is to have the host be headless. I just want the host to boot, then boot the VM, and for the guest VM to take over the VGA/DVI output.
